# Is there a functionality in java where I can count the amount of tokens on each line from an input file?

Tags: java, count, line, token

Is there a way I can specify to only count up to the end of the line?

Comment: What's wrong with using BufferedReader.readLine() or LineNumberReader.readLine()?

Comment: is there any specific format?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `String line = scanner.nextLine()` to read in a whole line at a time as a string (you'll probably want to check `scanner.hasNextLine()` first). Then you have options as to how to actually count the tokens (`StringTokenizer`'s `countTokens()` [method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/stringtokenizer_counttokens.htm) looks promising :) ), but find a way to count all of the tokens in that string. Then move on to the next line after that (use `scanner.hasNextLine()` to make sure there is another line), and repeat.